# PostrgreSQL: "-bash: postgres: command not found" right after installing with homebrew

Tags: postgresql, osx-elcapitan

Trying to get started learning django using PostgreSQL.

After installing PostgreSQL on Mac OSX El Capitan with homebrew, I see these words:

```
To have launchd start postgresql at login:
  ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/postgresql/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents
Then to load postgresql now:
  launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
Or, if you don't want/need launchctl, you can just run:
  postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres    
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.5.0: 3,113 files, 35.0M
```

But then when I type in exactly what it said to type, I get an error:

```
redacted_name:~ redacted$ postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres
-bash: postgres: command not found
```

????

There doesn't even seem to be a `/usr/local/var/` directory to begin with!

Wat?

**EDIT:**

Someone voted this closed, saying it's not about programming? Where should this  question be asked then? When I search 'postgreSQL mac' on Stack Exchange, most of the other questions are on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Just a hint: the title of the question is misleading. It's nothing related with django but with the homebrew postgres installation in mac osx. Maybe a community about mac should work better

Answer (score 1):

This was all I needed:

`brew link postgresql`

Hope this helps someone else!